# How to avoid summing duplicates in SQLAlchemy with many-to-many relationships?

Tags: join, select, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have 3 SQLAlchemy tables: TagGroup, Tag and Video. TagGroup/Tag and Tag/Video both have bi-directional many-to-many relationships with each other, specified with an association table. I want to construct a query that sums Video.viewCount field for all videos given some TagGroup.id. However, if the same video is linked to 2 separate Tag tables that are inside the same TagGroup, Video.viewCount will get summed twice. Would appreciate any help to avoid this.

E.g.

```
                  Video1
                /
           Tag1
         /      \
 TagGroup         Video2 (will get summed twice)
         \      /
           Tag2
                \
                  Video3
```

NB I have remove all unrelated fields for simplicity.

## Tag Group Model:

```py
class TagGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tag_groups"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True,
    )

    tags = relationship(
        "Tag",
        secondary=tags_and_groups_association_table,
        back_populates="groups",
    )
```

## Tag Group - Tag Association Table:

```py
tags_and_groups_association_table = Table(
    "tags_and_groups_association_table",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("tags_id", ForeignKey("tags.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("tag_groups_id", ForeignKey("tag_groups.id"), primary_key=True),
    PrimaryKeyConstraint('tags_id', 'tag_groups_id')  # to avoid duplicates.
)
```

## Tag Model:

```py
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True,
    )

    in_videos = relationship("Video", secondary=video_tags, back_populates="tags",lazy="select")

    groups = relationship(
        "TagGroup",
        secondary=tags_and_groups_association_table,
        back_populates="tags",
    )
```

## Tag - Video Association Table:

```py
video_tags = Table(
    'video_tags', Base.metadata,
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('video_id', Integer, ForeignKey('videos.id'), primary_key=True)
)
```

## Video Model:

```py
class Video(Base):
    __tablename__ = "videos"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True,
    )
    viewCount: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        BigInteger,
        nullable=False,
        default=0,
    )

    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary=video_tags, back_populates="in_videos", lazy="select")
```

I have tried various combinations with distinct or group_by video.id, but nothing seems to work.

```py
select(
    TagGroup.id,
    func.SUM(Video.viewCount),
    func.COUNT(distinct(Video.id)),  # count works perfectly well with distinct() by unique id.
).select_from(
    TagGroup.id
).where(
    TagGroup.id.in_(ids) # list of TagGroup ids 
).join(
    tags_and_groups_association_table,
    TagGroup.id == tags_and_groups_association_table.c.tag_groups_id
).join(
    Tag,
    tags_and_groups_association_table.c.tags_id == Tag.id
).join(
    video_tags_model,
    Tag.id == video_tags_model.c.tag_id,
).join(
    Video,
    video_tags_model.c.video_id == Video.id
).group_by(
    TagGroup.id,
)
```

Comment: I think it should be something with subquery

Comment: I have also tried the subquery approach but got the same issue... Perhaps I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it works, but try on more test cases.

If you confirm that it works well, I will add more comments to my answer a bit later.

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Integer, ForeignKey, Column, PrimaryKeyConstraint, Table, BigInteger, create_engine, select, func
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Mapped, mapped_column, DeclarativeBase, sessionmaker


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


tags_and_groups_association_table = Table(
    "tags_and_groups_association_table",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("tags_id", ForeignKey("tags.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("tag_groups_id", ForeignKey("tag_groups.id"), primary_key=True),
    PrimaryKeyConstraint('tags_id', 'tag_groups_id')  # to avoid duplicates.
)


class TagGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tag_groups"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True,
    )

    tags = relationship(
        "Tag",
        secondary=tags_and_groups_association_table,
        back_populates="groups",
    )



video_tags = Table(
    'video_tags', Base.metadata,
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('video_id', Integer, ForeignKey('videos.id'), primary_key=True)
)


class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True,
    )

    in_videos = relationship("Video", secondary=video_tags, back_populates="tags",lazy="select")

    groups = relationship(
        "TagGroup",
        secondary=tags_and_groups_association_table,
        back_populates="tags",
    )


class Video(Base):
    __tablename__ = "videos"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True,
    )
    viewCount: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        BigInteger,
        nullable=False,
        default=0,
    )

    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary=video_tags, back_populates="in_videos", lazy="select")



engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


with session_maker() as session:
    t_gr_1 = TagGroup()

    t_gr_2 = TagGroup()

    t_1 = Tag()
    t_2 = Tag()
    t_3 = Tag()
    t_4 = Tag()

    t_gr_1.tags.append(t_1)
    t_gr_1.tags.append(t_2)

    t_gr_2.tags.append(t_3)
    t_gr_2.tags.append(t_4)

    v_1 = Video(viewCount=111, tags=[t_1, t_2])
    v_2 = Video(viewCount=222, tags=[t_1, t_3])
    v_3 = Video(viewCount=444, tags=[t_3, t_4])
    v_4 = Video(viewCount=444, tags=[t_3])

    session.add(t_gr_1)
    session.add(t_gr_2)
    session.commit()


    ids = [1, 2]

    subq = (
        select(Video.viewCount.label("viewCount"), TagGroup.id.label("taggroup_id"))
            .select_from(TagGroup)
            .join(tags_and_groups_association_table)
            .join(Tag)
            .join(video_tags)
            .join(Video)
            .group_by(TagGroup.id, Video.id).subquery()
    )


    st = (
        select(subq.c.taggroup_id, func.SUM(subq.c.viewCount))
            .select_from(subq)
            .group_by(subq.c.taggroup_id)
    )

    for row in session.execute(st).all():
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
(1, 333)
(2, 1110)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for having a look at this!
I think, there is an issue when there are identical viewCounts for 2 videos (say, both are 20) - it will only sum one of them, since it groups by viewCount.

Using:

    func.SUM(distinct(Video.viewCount))

instead of:

    func.SUM(Video.viewCount) 

in my original attempt produces the same result.

Comment: You right. It was my mistake, I wanted to group by `Video.id` but confused the name..
I updated the answer, now it passes this test case.

Comment: That works, thank you!